# list of hashes from sql query in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have multiple tests in **DB** and I want to read and store all tests in list of **arrays** like `[{},{},{},....]`

currently my code returns the first row only in **all_test**

```
all_test=[]

test_query = "select ALL nameTest,version,start_date,TimeStamp,duration from Tests where start_date = \"#{test_date}\";"
     
all_test = @db.query(test_query).to_a[0]

pp all_test

output is:
{"nameTest"=>"basicTest", "version"=>"1.1", "start_date"=>"2022-10-10", "TimeStamp"=>2022-10-10 23:12:43 +0200,"duration"=>3023}
```

Edit:

apparently i need to loop through .to_a[i] unless its .nil? or i=size of rows,

UPDATE: its done, Thank you

Comment: can you please also add the expected output as well in your question?

Comment: You can replace this `all_test = @db.query(test_query).to_a[0]` with `all_test = @db.query(test_query).to_a` and check

Comment: if i do with only .to_a then error : spec/testutils/database.rb:116:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError).

Comment: apparently i have to loop throug .to_a[i] unless nil?   ; but i dont know how can i achieve this

Comment: can i do something like:  i=0                                                                                                                             if  all_test= @db.query(test_query).to_a[i].nil?
      pp all_test
      i += 1
    end

Comment: Its done i do:

    while @db.query(test_query).to_a[i] != nil
      all_test = @db.query(test_query).to_a[i]
      i +=1
      warn "#{all_test}"
    end
and output is three arrays {},{},{}.   what i want to have now is list of arrays like all in [{},{},{}]

Answer (score 0):

Its done i do:

```
while @db.query(test_query).to_a[i] != nil
  all_test = @db.query(test_query).to_a[i]
  i +=1
  warn "#{all_test}"
end
```

and output is three arrays {},{},{}.   Then, to get a list of arrays like all in [{},{},{}], that is done with <<